# Expecting an identifier in Neteeza?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select dt_bill from db_activity 
(
select dt_bill bill_date , to_date(dt_bill, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  bill_date
from db_activity a
where 1=1   
)
where bill_date > to_date('01-JAN-0001')
```

I am trying to change the date that's set in a certain format to another format, not sure why it gives me this error:

> ERROR [42000] ERROR:
>   found "SELECT" (at char 47) expecting an identifier found a keyword */

By the way, I'm using Netezza, the Aginity workbench.

Comment: WHERE 1 = 1 is always true you can leave that out

Answer (score 1):

Everyone was correct in some way shape or form, it seems as though the syntax I was working with in Oracle was not the same for this database.

For those working with Neteeza, make sure to understand how to link certain databases to which tables you are calling for example : databasename.tablename. Please refer to those who are working with you who are most familiar with the database. How this query SHOULD'VE been written:

```
select c.dt_cash, 
   c.at_pmt, 
   c.ky_ba, 
   d.dt_bill, 
   b.cd_res_comm, 
   to_date(d.dt_bill, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as bill_date, 
   sum (d.at_db) as sum_at_db
from css_p.source.cr_srce c -- **Notice how the database source is linked**
    join css_p.source.db_activity d 
          on d.KY_BA= c.ky_ba
   join css_p.source.bill_acct b --***schema name css_p is linked here****
          on b.ky_ba = c.ky_ba 
where d.dt_bill>= '2016-01-01' 
and d.dt_bill<= '2016-04-01'
and b.CD_RES_COMM = 'R'
and c.KY_BA = XXXXXXXX -- **number is blocked out per privacy regulations**
group by c.dt_cash, 
   c.at_pmt, 
   c.ky_ba, 
   d.dt_bill, 
   b.cd_res_comm
```

So notice how it's a tad bit different then how you're used to working in Oracle. 
Hope this helps some of you out!

Answer (score 0):

I belive you forgot a comma "," character between select `dt_bill` and `bill_date`. In this case the column `dt_bill` got the name of `bill_date` column.

Your script is supose to look like.

```
select dt_bill from db_activity 
(
select dt_bill, to_date(dt_bill, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  bill_date
from db_activity a

)
where bill_date > to_date('01-JAN-0001')
```

Comment: WHERE 1 = 1 is always true you can leave that out

Comment: yeah, it really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Comment: you can thank people who help you by upvoting their answer and/or marking his answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from a syntax error you made querying a derived table. You seem to be querying a table name but then follow it with parentheses for a derive table subquery.

```
select dt_bill from db_activity 
(
select ...
```

If you want to only query from the derived table, then remove `db_activity`.

If you want to query a real table called `db_activity` joined with the derived table, then add some JOIN syntax.

Either way, you must give any derived table a table alias. So you should have written:

```
select dt_bill from  
(
select ...
) as d
where ...
```

You also have another problem, which will cause a new error once you resolve the first problem. It's in your subquery:

```
select dt_bill bill_date , to_date(dt_bill, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  bill_date
```

This is trying to use `bill_date` as the alias for two different columns, which is not allowed in a subquery. All column names must be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

select dt_bill from
    (
    select dt_bill bill_date , to_date(dt_bill, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  chk_bill_date
    from db_activity a
    where 1=1
    )
 b
    where bill_date > to_date('01-JAN-0001', 'dd-mon-yyyy')

Pls make sure the column names should be unique. 
2. Remember to_date should contain date format.